# Deformation of the trivial line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal L)$ be a deformation over a (smooth) base $B$ of the pair $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ where $X$ is a smooth projective variety (over $\mathbb C$).
Is the class $c_1(\mathcal L_b)\in \mathrm{NS}(X_b)$ always trivial?
(we can assume the $X_b$ to be projective).

Comment: Assuming $B$ is connected, then yes, because the $C^\infty$ structure of the pair $(X_b, L_b)$ won't change.

Comment: By the way, this is false over a regular base scheme of mixed characteristic, cf. Enriques surfaces that are "singular" and "supersingular".

Comment: @Donu Arapura Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Jason Starr Thanks also for the information.